# SharePoint Online List Form settings

Tags: powerapp

I am getting an unusual error on my SharePoint Online list form settings section. It shows:

> This list doesn't have a valid content type.

No idea why it shows.

I can also confirm that I am using the 'Modern Experience' rather the classic.

Regards
Antony

Comment: I am using content type in the library and it is published from the Hub. This is happening to every library of the site.

Answer (score 2):

Issue solved.

The content type was locked for updates.

once I unlocked the content type for updates, it worked.

Cheers.